# How to insert sized traits into a collection

Tags: rust

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=35c37268fceec64573e1918d5631c40c&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

```
#[derive(Default)]
struct Bar;

#[derive(Default)]
struct Baz;

fn main() {
    let mut vec = Vec::<Box<dyn Default>>::new();
//                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::default::Default` cannot be made into an object
    vec.push(Box::new(Bar));
    vec.push(Box::new(Baz));
}
```

[Default](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/default.rs.html#94-126) is a sized Trait, which means you [cannot convert it to a trait object](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Sized.html).

For the example above, is there a workaround so I can store sized traits in a `Vec` (or any other collection)?

Comment: I don't think that there're any workarounds. What's the point of having a vector of Defaults? How should it even work?

Comment: You could call the method provided by the trait (in this case `default`), like with any other trait too.

Comment: You want to make a factory ?

Comment: @hellow it's a factory function that doesn't take `self`. There's no point in trying to call it with some already existing object like `obj.default()`.

Comment: @ozkriff I have added this point to my answer

Comment: Damn... You're right. How am I supposed to call a "constructor" on a already created object... Valid point! Thanks, for making me to understand this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do such a thing because of the object safety rule. This rule says that a trait which a method returns the concrete type itself cannot be made into a trait object. The reason is that the trait object would have known the concrete type.

Also, this trait has no method (a function that takes `self`), so there is no point to make a trait object from it.

See more about this rule [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch17-02-trait-objects.html#object-safety-is-required-for-trait-objects), [there](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0255-object-safety.md) and in this [blog article](https://huonw.github.io/blog/2015/01/object-safety/).

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45116984/the-trait-cannot-be-made-into-an-object).

---

This rule is pretty intuitive: what do you expect your code to do?

```
#[derive(Default)]
struct Bar;

#[derive(Default)]
struct Baz;

fn main() {
    let mut vec = Vec::<Box<dyn Default>>::new();
    vec.push(Box::new(Bar));
    vec.push(Box::new(Baz));

    vec.first().unwrap()::new();
    // Whatever the syntax should be, what do you expect this to return?
    // This type cannot be know at compile time.
}
```

Comment: How often I've wished that the rule was the other way around: ie, allow such traits to be boxed, etc... but only allow access to the subset of their interface which is object safe.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I think this is possible and that would be retrocompatible. Let's do an RFC ;)