# Abstract function receiving and returning Rc

Tags: rust

I'm being unable to compile the following:

```
pub trait Symbol : ToString {
    fn callee(self: &Rc<Self>) -> Option<Rc<dyn Symbol>> {
        None
    }
}
```

Taking `Rc` parameter causes the error...

> E0038) the trait `symbols::Symbol` cannot be made into an object

everywhere `Symbol` is used, including in that function declaration.

It does work if I take `&self` instead of `self: &Rc<Self>`, however I've some functions that really need to take this Rc. Any idea of what to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The trait cannot be made into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45116984/the-trait-cannot-be-made-into-an-object)

Comment: @Jmb This seems to be about a field, while I'm dealing with a trait's method (dynamic dispatch or late binding).

Comment: See also https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety

Comment: Note that it should work with `fn callee (self: Rc<Self>)`

Comment: @Jmb I've just tried it, the only problem is that doing this will move ownership to the first call to `callee()`, but looks like that is what I can do for now. Thanks!

Comment: You can clone if you don't want to move ownership (cloning an `Rc` is cheap whatever the inner type is).

Answer (score 0):

Notice this error message:

```rust
error[E0307]: invalid `self` parameter type: Rc<(dyn Symbol + 'static)>
 --> src/lib.rs:3:21
  |
3 |     fn callee(self: Rc<dyn Symbol>) -> Option<Rc<dyn Symbol>> {
  |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: type of `self` must be `Self` or a type that dereferences to it
  = help: consider changing to `self`, `&self`, `&mut self`, `self: Box<Self>`, `self: Rc<Self>`, `self: Arc<Self>`, or `self: Pin<P>` (where P is one of the previous types except `Self`)
```

It should be a `Rc<Self>`, it makes not much sense of using `&Rc` since `Rc` is cheap to clone.

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;
pub trait Symbol : ToString {
    fn callee(self: Rc<Self>) -> Option<Rc<dyn Symbol>> {
        None
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9b4be13b5312cac2ea466834fa858fe0)